# 2 Fixed navigation bars full browser width and height

Tags: html, css, navigation, position, fixed

I want to position:fix a navigation to the left side of the browser window (100% height). Then on the right side I want to fix a subnav to the top of the browser window (100% width) so that as the page scrolls, both navs stick. And if the window is resized, the bars always run 100%.

I almost have it, the only problem is that the top navbar doesnt take into account the width of the left nav. So it lets you scrolls laterally. Here's my html/css:

```
     html, body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: left;
}

    div.leftnav {    
        width: 160px;
        height: 100%;
        float: left;
        display: inline;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 20px;
    }

    div.rightpage { 
        float: left;
        margin: 0;
        padding-left: 200px; 
        width: 100%; 
        height: 100%; 
    }

    div.rightpage div.topnav {
        width: 100%;
        height: 20px;
        float: left;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 15px;
        display: inline;
    }

    div.rightpage div.content {
        padding: 50px;
        min-height: 1200px;
    }

    <body>
        <div class="leftnav">
        </div>
        <div class="rightpage">
            <div class="topnav"></div>
            <div class="content"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Help?? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `calc` function to make the `.rightpage` the correct width.

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.leftnav {
  width: 160px;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: blue;
}

.rightpage {
  width: calc(100% - 160px);
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 160px;
  background: red;
}

.topnav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  left: 160px;
  top: 0;
  background: green;
}
```

Check out this [codepen demo](http://codepen.io/the_ruther4d/pen/3d8d8fa03f821e96a743fd944a32a1aa/)

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I am going for! Thanks! What's the browser support like for the calc function? I have seen this nav structure in a lot of different websites, do you think they are mostly using the calc function method? Or is there a better practice?

Comment: You can see the full compatibility chart <a href="http://caniuse.com/#search=calc">here</a>. Support is decent on desktop browsers, but Android and older mobile Safari are bad. You could consider using percentage widths to avoid this, with media queries to support. Alternatively you could do something like this: http://codepen.io/the_ruther4d/pen/2bc0ae867f211fbc9836bf55be5e3abb/?editors=010

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the help, Josh. My first stackoverflow experience has been a great one!

Comment: Great to hear @Jake86atx!

Answer (score 0):

You could add

```
div.rightpage div.topnav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    float: left;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15px 15px 15px 160px; //Would force the whole of topnav content to the left 160px..
    display: inline;
}
```

Edit:... I would potentially add `-moz-box-sizing:border-box; box-sizing: border-box;` to at least this element. It will prevent your 100% elements from going out of bounds from the padding.

Comment: I already have my left padding on the container div.rightpage. So that works, problem is my content is going out of bounds 200px to the right. So when I adjust the window size the text wraps, but its out of bounds.

Comment: Yea you would want to have the box-sizing for the width to be set. The padding pushes it out, but the box-sizing will mess it up. You will want to use box-sizing with the actual answer to this as well just in case your padding pushes it out. It is good practice.